# Spanish translation for "also"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, definiciones, sinónimos, adverbios

My understanding is that `también`, and `asimismo` can both be translated from Spanish as "also."

Yet there appear to be some subtle differences. What are they? For instance, does `asimismo` also mean "furthermore"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*also*.

- «**también**» cuando tiene valor de *too* o *as well*.
- «**además**» cuando tiene valor de *further*, *besides*, *moreover* o *additionally*.

Answer (score 12):

I would say that, most of the time, "also"  is translated as "también."

"[Asismimo](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=asimismo)" is normally used as "likewise" in English, which is also a synonym of "también."

Comment: Sometimes can be translated as "además" too.

Comment: @Laura, instead you could have said: 'Sometimes it can *also* be translated as "además".' ;-)

Comment: @StephaneRolland :D you're absolutely right